# PHP / CSV Export - Blank Row Issue

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, export

I have an issue during CSV export (Via a simple .html button).
The first row before header is empty. this cause some issue during excel import (If i'm not removing the first blank row manually, the ... last row of the file is not imported).

So i'm trying to remove the first blank row, but I don't really know how to do this during the export.

See below the php code export the data to .csv (Working) :

```
<?php

// Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [cm_blueprint] WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY cm_blueprint_name";
$msdb = new DB();
$result = $msdb->runQuery($sql);
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Zurich");

// Array
$data = array();
While($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = array(
        "cm_blueprint_id"               =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_id']),
        "cm_blueprint_name"             =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_name']),
        "cm_blueprint_type"             =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_type']),
        "cm_blueprint_vradatecreated"   =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_vradatecreated']->format('Y-m-d G:i:s')),
        "cm_blueprint_vralastupdated"   =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_vralastupdated']->format('Y-m-d G:i:s')),
        "cm_blueprint_description"      =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_description']),
        "cm_blueprint_service"          =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_service']),
        "cm_blueprint_status"           =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_status']),
        "cm_blueprint_version"          =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_version']),
        "cm_blueprint_requestable"      =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_requestable']),
        "cm_blueprint_tenant"           =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_tenant']),
        "cm_blueprint_output"           =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_output']),
        "cm_blueprint_quota"            =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_quota']),
        "cm_blueprint_createdtime"      =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_createdtime']->format('Y-m-d G:i:s')),
        "cm_blueprint_lastupdate "      =>  utf8_encode($row['cm_blueprint_lastupdate']->format('Y-m-d G:i:s'))
    );
}

// Export Part
$file = "cm_blueprint.csv";

// Headers
$headers = array();
foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata($result) as $fieldMetadata){
    $headers[] = $fieldMetadata['Name'];
}   

// File to export
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');       
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);

// Array export
foreach ($data as $fields) {fputcsv($fp, $fields);}     
break;

?>
```

And here what's the .csv looks like :

[image: CSv Sample]

I've check for blank row / space in the php code, nothing.
If you have any suggestion ...

Thanks for your help.

Edit 30.12.2019 var_dump($headers);

```
array(15) { [0]=> string(21) "cm_blueprint_id" [1]=> string(23) "cm_blueprint_name" [2]=> string(23) "cm_blueprint_type" [3]=> string(33) "cm_blueprint_vradatecreated" [4]=> string(33) "cm_blueprint_vralastupdated" [5]=> string(30) "cm_blueprint_description" [6]=> string(26) "cm_blueprint_service" [7]=> string(25) "cm_blueprint_status" [8]=> string(26) "cm_blueprint_version" [9]=> string(30) "cm_blueprint_requestable" [10]=> string(25) "cm_blueprint_tenant" [11]=> string(25) "cm_blueprint_output" [12]=> string(24) "cm_blueprint_quota" [13]=> string(30) "cm_blueprint_createdtime" [14]=> string(29) "cm_blueprint_lastupdate" }
```

Comment: Can you show a `var_dump($headers)`?

Comment: I've edited with the var_dump($headers);

Comment: I tried that locally in console and worked well without the extra newline. Can you try testing this in console, too?